# jquery update content using user text input text

Tags: jquery

good day, I have this html:

```
<div class="subcategory_name_wrapper" id="categories">

<div class="subcategory_name">
      <a href="#1">apple
      </a>
      </div>
<div class="subcategory_name">
      <a href="#2">plum
      </a>
      </div>
<div class="subcategory_name">
      <a href="#3">cherry
      </a>
      </div>
</div>
```

I want to filter the subcategories using jquery and an text input, when the use types, the content is updated (filtered) as per his input. for example if he types cherry, only that div is sh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$('#inputtext').on('keyup',function(e){
var searchValue=this.value,
selector='a:contains("'+searchValue+'")',
$allDivParents = $('.subcategory_name');

$allDivParents .hide();
var $validDivsParents = $(selector).parent();
$validDivsParents.show();
})
```

http://codepen.io/JDev02/pen/YpXoQB

Comment: What modifications do I need to make to the function for the match to be caSe InsenSitive?

Comment: use filter function for get your  elements collection... after hide or show your elements
http://codepen.io/JDev02/pen/xRwdYR

regars